# Нужно реализовать отсчет времени на экране 3 2 1 Go!

Tags: c#, unity3d

Сделал обычный отсчет времени от 3 секунд до 0. Но нужно чтобы вместо 0 писалось (Go!) и отсчет времени при этом останавливался

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float timeStart = 3;
    public Text timerText;
    void Start()
    {
        timerText.text = timeStart.ToString();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        timeStart -= Time.deltaTime;
        timerText.text = Mathf.Round(timeStart).ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[SerializeField] private Text Timer; // Объект таймера
[Header("Параметры таймера")]
[SerializeField] private int Delay = 3f; // Сколько ждем
[SerializeField] private string TimesUpText = "GO!"; // Какой текст покажем, когда время истечет


private IEnumerator TimerCountdown() // Обратный отсчет таймера
{
    while (Delay > 0)
    {
        SetTimerText(Delay--);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    }

    SetTimerText("GO!");
}

private void SetTimerText (string text) {
    Timer.text = text;
    // Здесь можно добавить какую-либо анимацию, например, что текст появляется "ударами": большой, потом уменьшается; либо изменяется цвет и т.д.
}
```

Если хотите, чтобы после показа "GO!" текст исчез в конец корутины `TimerCountdown` добавьте следующие строки:

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f); // Сколько ждем
Timer.text = "";
```

Если вы захотите сделать ожидание дробным или, например, показывать обратный отсчет с десятыми/сотыми, то Delay нужно сделать float. Но я такого в гонках почти никогда не видел.

Этот код можно поместить в класс `Timer`, повешенный на объект таймера. В таком случае переменную Timer можно сделать приватной и кэшировать в Awake:

```
private void Awake () {
    Timer = GetComponent<Timer>();
}
```

Ну и еще в такое случае было бы неплохо добавить перед объявлением класса

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Text))]
```

Ссылки:

- Coroutine: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html
- WaitForSeconds: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html
- RequireComponent: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RequireComponent.html

Answer (score 1):

Можно реализовать через [Coroutine](https://habr.com/ru/post/216185/).
Вызывается в Start(). IEnumerator используют yield. yield return возвращает нeкое значение и переходит к следующему блоку кода, в данном случае используется `yield return new WaitForSeconds(n);` где `n` - время в секундах.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float timeStart = 3;
    public Text timerText;
    void Start()
    {
        timerText.text = timeStart.ToString();
        StartCoroutine(TimerCoroutine());
    }
    IEnumerator TimerCoroutine()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
            
            --timeStart;
            if (timeStart == 0)
            {
                timerText.text = "Go";
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                timerText.text = timeStart.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не то чтобы я не любил Хабр, но ссылка на официальную документацию в ответах является более предпочтительной или, как минимум, не лишней :)

Comment: @МаксимФисман Я тоже предпочитаю использовать и оставлять документацию, но в данном случае ссылка на habr посчитал более информативней чем документация